# Microsoft Azure - 2 VMs behind a public facing Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I want to have 2 VMs behind a public facing `Load Balancer`. Both the VMs are in an `Availability Set` spread across 2 fault domains and 5 update domains (the defaults set for availability sets on the portal).

Strangely, the `Load Balancer` does show the `Availability Set` when I try to configure the `Backend Pool` and hence I'm unable to configure `Inbound NAT Rules` for the VMs.

Both the VMs do not have public IPs. They just have their private IPs.

How do I proceed ?

Comment: you should be able to proceed, whats the error? the config looks right

Comment: The availability set option does not show up the drop down when I go to configure backend pools for the load balancer.

Comment: Oops! The question states right. The comment was a typo.

Comment: ok, i'm confused, can you show a screenshot? also delete the comments if they are misleading

Answer (score 0):

> Strangely, the Load Balancer does show the Availability Set when I try
>   to configure the Backend Pool and hence I'm unable to configure
>   Inbound NAT Rules for the VMs. Both the VMs do not have public IPs.
>   They just have their private IPs.

If I understanding is right, you'are unable to configure inbound NAT rules since the frontend public IP is not assigned. (I have the same experience before). Once I finished Health probe and Load Balancer rule configurations. The frontend IP address is assigned and shown.

I believe you know how to configure the NAT rule, you can get more details from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal#create-inbound-nat-rules).

Comment: Update, hopefully, this helps.